# How to insert data into firebase but it will displayed after being approved by the admin app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making 2 android app, app 1 is for the user, and app 2 is for admin, is it possible if I upload data to firebase from app 1, and will be displayed after being approved by the admin in the second application?

I have tried using 2 tables in firebase, but duplicate data occurred in admin and user app
[here my firebase database tables pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYHHD.png)

Comment: Your solution is ok in my opinion, there is no problem with duplicated data in noSQL since you have to design it around your queries. Also I believe you would delete the data from Datatoadmin node as soon as admin approved so I really think that your solution is ok and there is nothing wrong with duplicated data, but you can try @Luca solution, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest way is to add a field to every uploaded data which checks wether the data got checked by an admin or not.

Then you could query in app 1 for the data that has for example `checkedByAdmin: true` and in app 2 for `checkedByAdmin: false`.

I don't think there would be an easier way.